# One line plot title with multiple texts and num2str elements

Tags: matlab, plot, title

I was wondering is there a way to put titles on MATLAB plots with text and num2str elements separated by manually specified spaces.

Here I can do it in multiple lines as below for instance:

```
title({['a1 =' num2str(a1)],['a2 =' num2str(a2)],['$\varphi_1$ =' num2str(phi1)],['$\varphi_2$ =' num2str(phi2)],['$\varphi_3$ =' num2str(phi3)]},'Interpreter','LaTex')
```

But how can I keep elements in one line with manually specified spaces in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only have one set of square brackets and lose the curly braces, and use spaces within the strings where you want additional space.

```
title(['a1 =' num2str(a1) ' a2 =' num2str(a2) ' ....
    $\varphi_1$ =' num2str(phi1) ' $\varphi_2$ =' num2str(phi2) ' ... 
    $\varphi_3$='num2str(phi3)], ... 
    'Interpreter','LaTex')
```